# mysql: error 1349 al crear una vista

Tags: mysql

Al tratar de crear una vista en mysql:

```
CREATE VIEW product_views AS
     SELECT u.* , v.name AS img_name FROM products AS u
     LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT x.name, x.id_prod, x.id FROM images AS x
       RIGHT JOIN
       (SELECT min(id) AS id FROM images AS y
         LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT id_prod, max(`first`) AS `first`
         FROM images GROUP BY id_prod) AS z
         ON z.id_prod = y.id_prod
         WHERE z.`first` = y.`first`
         GROUP BY y.id_prod) AS w
       ON x.id = w.id) AS v
     ON v.id_prod = u.id'
```

aparece el siguiente mensaje de error:

> ## 1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

---

CONTEXTO:

mi objetivo es conseguir una tabla con todas las columnas de la tabla products y agregarle una columna (img_name) que contenga el campo images.name:

1. el campo name de images, de existir un registro en images con id_prod == products.id y first == true.
2. si no se cumple el anterior pero existe al menos 1 registro en images con id_prod == products.id, obtener un name de alli.
3. si el anterior tampoco se cumple, solo null.

Logre crear una vista desde HeidiSQL(funciona correctamente y todo) con ese código pero no en phpmyadmin en un hosting

columnas tabla product

- id
- ....

columnas tabla images

- id
- id_prod
- name
- first
- ...

editado:

Versión del servidor: 10.1.37-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server

Comment: que version de mysql estas usando? igual, por lo que veo, es muy pero muy probable que tu query se pueda optimizar un monton

Comment: Versión del servidor: 10.1.37-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
lo edito en el post ahora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te dice el mensaje, el uso de subconsultas en el FROM es ilegal en las VIEW de MYSQL.
Lo que te conviene en ese caso es crear otra VIEW para que realice esa subconsulta y ponerla como tabla de la mayor.
AL menos en este DBMS no es posible el uso de las subqueries en esas condiciones.

En esencia, para que funcione sin subconsultas, cada nivel de subconsulta debe ser creado como una vista, y para que funcione deben ser creadas en orden inverso, de la más interior a la exterior:

```
CREATE VIEW product_first AS
    SELECT 
        id_prod, MAX(`first`) `first`
    FROM
        images
    GROUP BY id_prod;

CREATE VIEW product_second AS
    SELECT 
        MIN(id) AS id
    FROM
        images y
            LEFT JOIN
        product_first z ON z.id_prod = y.id_prod
    WHERE
        z.`first` = y.`first`
    GROUP BY y.id_prod;

CREATE VIEW product_third AS
    SELECT 
        x.name, x.id_prod, x.id
    FROM
        images x
            RIGHT JOIN
        product_second AS w ON x.id = w.id;

CREATE VIEW product_views AS
     SELECT u.* , v.name  img_name FROM products  u
     LEFT JOIN
     product_third v
     ON v.id_prod = u.id;
```

Francamente, yo te sugeriría hacer esa consulta directamente dentro de un stored procedure y que la aplicación lo consuma. Sería mas simple...

Comment: Un ejemplo vendría bien y haría a la respuesta de mejor calidad

Comment: tu respuesta me sirvió perfecto, y la marque como correcta. Eso si como dice alfa p, si das un ejemplo  o un link relacionado con tu sugerencia seria genial y te lo agradecería